# Apple new requirements on submitting app that say must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, iphone-x

I see a post in Apple News and Update 
[Upcoming iOS 11 App Update Requirements](http://%20Upcoming%20iOS%2011%20App%20Update%20Requirements).

> Starting July 2018, all iOS app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK and must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X

My App support iOS 11 and working in latest Xcode9.4 and after reading this news I added iPhoneX SplashScreen to support iPhoneX but views in app disturbed in iPhoneX like navigation bar because of not enable safe area in Views. Here below is screenshot of one of view.
[image]
So My questions are

- Will Apple accept my app by only adding Splashscreen(to Support iPhoneX) or will I need to support or adjust all views or screens according to iPhoneX sizes If I submit after July 2018 ?
- There are more than 100 screens in my App so how quickly I'll adjust according to iPhoneX size(majorly I feel Navigation bar and search bar issue on top) ?

Looking for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: you will need to go through each page and start supporting the safe area. This will take less time than you think and is better in the long run as this is the new interface Apple has for displaying content.

Comment: @atreat What about If I'll not support each page but only Support App like added Splash Screen to support app according to iPhoneX, will Apple accept my app after july. Any Idea?

Comment: Is the image in the screenshot the experience you want people to have of your app when using Apple's flagship phone? I wouldn't think so and I don't think Apple would either. Your app would most likely be rejected as it doesn't support iPhone X correctly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your comments, So what will be quickest solution to support around 100 screens ?

Comment: There is no magic bullet.  You need to go into each scene in your storyboard and make sure that the constraints are set correctly to respect the safe area layout guide.